# How to stop rendering page/partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I interested about can I interupt template rendering in the middle of template. For example:

*items/index.html.haml*

```
%h2 Items

-if @items.empty?
  %h3 There are no items
  /X statement/ 


-@items.each do |item|
  /items rendering/
```

So if there are no items, message will be displayed and page rendering will be interrupted, otherwise item list will be rendered. Only way I can do it now, is throw if-else statement. I tried to use **return** in place of *X statement*, but seems like it not works like I expect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to achieve that result is exactly by using the if-else statement.

I'm not familiar with Haml, but the logic using the good "old" ERB is

```
<% if @items.empty? %>
  There are no items
<% else %>
  <% @items.each do |item| %>
  ...
  <% end %>    
<% end %>
```

You can use a double if, if you prefer to split the conditions

```
<% if @items.empty? %>
  There are no items
<% end %>    

<% @items.each do |item| %>
...
<% end unless @items.empty? %>
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid if-else? Like die() function in PHP with only difference that die() works globally, and I want the same functional in scope of current file

Comment: Why do you want to go against nature? Even assuming there may be some sort of hack, the solution is really that simple: you should use the if-else flow control statements.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can't do this. What you can do is check if `@items` are empty BEFORE you start rendering items index:

```
- if @items.empty?
  %h3 There are no items
- else
  %h2 Items
  - @items.each do |item|
    /items rendering/
```